# Is there a way to check if the AccountName exists from Azure Storage account?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage-account

I was playing around with Storage accounts from Azure and I saw that invalid `AccountName` (from connectionString) doesn't throw an error that the `AccountName` is invalid, instead it times out after 20 seconds. I use a connection string to connect:

`BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);`

I saw some [resources](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/12744) that having `blobServiceClient.GetProperties();` might throw an error and by this way gain a knowledge that the `AccountName` is invalid but as I said, it times me out and having to wait 20 seconds isn't an option for my app before returning a message that the `AccountName` is invalid.

The error I get is `Retry failed after 6 tries`.

Why I'm doing this is because my app uses a few storage accounts so for each of them the user specifies which account to use. I'd like to handle the scenario where the user will type a storage account (name) which is not present at all.

Any ideas how can I check whether the given `AccountName` exists in my Storage account or not, from .NET?

Comment: There is a CLI command and the underlying REST API. Would that help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_check_name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/check-name-availability

Comment: Hm, so I cant really use it from a C# library? Thank you for the links tho @silent

Comment: not sure if that is also in the SDK to be honest

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas how can I check whether the given AccountName exists in my
> Storage account or not, from .NET?

You can use [`Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.storage?view=azure-dotnet) Namespace to perform management related operations on a storage account in particular [`StorageAccountsOperationsExtensions.GetPropertiesAsync(IStorageAccountsOperations, String, String, Nullable<StorageAccountExpand>, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.storage.storageaccountsoperationsextensions.getpropertiesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Storage_StorageAccountsOperationsExtensions_GetPropertiesAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Storage_IStorageAccountsOperations_System_String_System_String_System_Nullable_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Storage_Models_StorageAccountExpand__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method to see if the storage account exists in your Azure Subscription or not.

One of the problem you're facing is that it takes a long time to get the properties of your account using `BlobServiceClient.GetProperties()` method. You can cut down that time considerably by reducing the amount of retires that are performed by the SDK. By default the SDK retries a retryable operation 5 times (a total of 6 times). However you can configure the retry policy to not retry the operation. For example, please see the code below:

```
BlobClientOptions clientOptions = new BlobClientOptions()
{
    Retry =
    {
        MaxRetries = 0
    }
};
BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString, clientOptions);
var properties = await serviceClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
```

The code above will only try to get the properties once (no retries). You will have to capture any exception that `GetPropertiesAsync` method throws and determine if the storage account does not exist, the storage account key is invalid or the code failed because of some other reasons.